# Streaming txpool data instead of pulling whole dictionary on every iteration

Tags: web3js, web3.py, txpool

I've worked on a script that tracks if x token has received a liquidity transaction. The way this works is by calling on my Geth node txpool API. My issue is, my current implementation, which works on iterations, pulls the whole dictionary from txpool every single time, for example:

First iteration would pull a dictionary containing

A
B
C
D

Second iteration would pull a dictionary containing

E
A
C
D
B
F

How would I implement my code in a way that streams data continuously, instead of having to receive new data along with already processed one? With the previous example, the second iteration of my code should return only E and F
Here's my code

```
def liquidCheck(self, address):
        methodTarget = "0xf305d719" 
        while True:
            tx_data = self.w3.geth.txpool.content()["pending"] #This calls the txpool pending transactions
            try:
                for k, v in tx_data.items():
                    for k2, v2 in v.items():
                        methodId = v2.input[0:10]
                        if methodId.lower() != methodTarget.lower():
                            continue
                        token_addr = self.pancake_contract_instance.decode_function_input(v2.input)[1]["token"]
                        if token_addr.lower() == address.lower():
                            print(v2)
                            return
                print("Not found any activity within token holders, retrying")
            except:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: fetching the whole txpool is extremely compute infefficient, it will consume a lot of resources of the Node. Since the API doesn't expose any subscription functionality you will have to modify `geth` and add event subscription functionality yourself using Golang.

Comment: the good thing is that `geth` has all the functions made for this , and you can even make your own RPC function to push TxPool events to subscribers, here is the subscription functionality inside `geth` , you just need to use it: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/9624f92edef5e0a76a97efd302e983077acb6e35/core/tx_pool.go#L230

Comment: @Nulik thanks for info ! btw, have you ever seen already 'modified' code-example of geth which can push TxPool events ?